# Get entire paragraph by searching single word or multiple

Tags: awk, sed, grep, find

I need your help in scripting portion.

I have a configuration file for routers as below,

```
# TiMOS-C-16.0.R5-1 cpm/hops64 Nokia 7750 SR Copyright (c) 2000-2019 Nokia.

# All rights reserved. All use subject to applicable license agreements.

# Built on Fri Jan 18 10:59:23 PST 2019 by builder in /builds/c/160B/R5-1/panos/main


# Generated MON SEP 30 08:06:41 2019 UTC

exit all
configure
#--------------------------------------------------
echo "System Configuration"
#--------------------------------------------------
    system
        name "iLAB-SR-12-R2"
        ptp
            profile g8275dot1-2014
            clock-type boundary
        exit
        rollback
            rollback-location "cf3:/rollback"
        exit
        snmp
            streaming
                no shutdown
            exit
            packet-size 9216
        exit
        software-repository "SAS-Sx-image" create
            description "Ethernet Satellite SW rep"
            primary-location "cf3:\images\7210-SAS-Sx-TiMOS-10.0.R10"
        exit
        time
            ntp
                ntp-server authenticate
                authentication-key 1 key "9MwhaEG2ryE/jYWFp7Sa64ypYoc=" hash2 type message-digest
                no shutdown
            exit
            sntp
                shutdown
            exit
            zone SGT 08
        exit

#--------------------------------------------------
echo "System Time NTP Configuration"
#--------------------------------------------------
    system
        time
            ntp
                server ptp prefer
                server 129.250.35.251
            exit
        exit
    exit
```

So Mostly all the routers have the configuration file as above.

Now I have some key block files as below,

```
time
    ntp
        ntp-server authenticate
        authentication-key 1 key "9MwhaEG2ryE/jYWFp7Sa64ypYoc=" hash2 type message-digest
        no shutdown
    exit
    sntp
        shutdown
    exit
    zone SGT 08
exit

ptp
    profile g8275dot1-2014
    clock-type boundary
exit


    system
        login-control
            idle-timeout 60
        exit
    exit


system
    time
        ntp
            server ptp prefer
            server 129.250.35.251
        exit
    exit
exit
```

So I want to check the all key blocks file with router configurations to determine all the key block file are present in the router configurations.

I already stuck. Can anyone help to give solution. Whether I can use awk, sed or grep or any other tool.

Your help will be appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: Find your solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32380013 : ` awk '/authentication-key/' RS="\n\n" ORS="\n\n" /your/files/*`

Comment: Stuck at what point? I can't find your attempt with which you are stuck.

Comment: markgraf,
Bro, I want to check the entire paragraph of A is in B. Example,
```
A File:
interface 1/1
    port 1
B File:
interface 1/1
    port 1
```

Comment: Philippos, Bro i dont have much knowledge in script so that i says i stuck where and how to proceed because this want to compare entire paragraph with another paragraph.